# I tried to install VMware and there were error when reboot, how I can configure the virtual machine

Tags: vmware-fusion

I couldn't install and reboot VMware on Mac M2, how to configure the virtual machine, just it pop up the screen for the virtual machine with error from the beginning
The virtual machine open de firmware and it says over Iv6 error

I expect to install correctly de VMware fusion